# Save a worksheet with form Save As location in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Well, I am not a developer but an regular an Excel user try to automate some process while working so please understand if my question is of simple to do.

I just want to a macro that can when I run the macro, it will allow me to 
 Browse the computer so I can save the file in the direction and file name I like
If possible
 Default location is the location of the workbook, just to save time

Thank you

Comment: Please see Excel Help on `GetSaveAsFilename` Note while using the `Workbook.SaveAs` method to save a file you have to also take take of `FileFormat` That again is mentioned in the Excel Help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub SaveAsDailog()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim filePath As Variant
filePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("abcd.xlsx", "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

If VarType(filePath) = vbString Then
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filePath
End If


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: this allows me to save the whole workbook but not the active-sheet and there is error on  the extension.