# How can I save Worksheet A to folder A and worksheet B to folder B?

Tags: vba, excel, save

How can I save Sheet1 to Folder A and Sheet2 to Folder B in VBA Excel?
In my workbook I have 4 worksheets C back end and worksheet D is the interface.

Folder path are:

- `C:\Main Folder\Folder A\`
- `C:\Main Folder\Folder B\`

  ```
  FilePath1 = "C:\Main Folder\Folder A\"
  FilePath2 = "C:\Main Folder\Folder B\"

  Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
  Filename = ControlNumber.Value
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FilePath1 & "\" & Filename & ".xls"
  ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

  Sheets("Sheet2").Copy
  Filename = ControlNumber.Value
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FilePath2 & "\" & Filename & ".xls"
  ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save a worksheet with form Save As location in Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886130/save-a-worksheet-with-form-save-as-location-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Having a path ending with `...\ ` there is no need for `...th1 & "\" & File...`

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine for me this way

```
FilePath1 = "C:\Main Folder\Folder A\"
FilePath2 = "C:\Main Folder\Folder B\"

Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
Filename = ControlNumber.Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FilePath1 & Filename & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

Sheets("Sheet2").Copy
Filename = ControlNumber.Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FilePath2 & Filename & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

what errors do you get?

for testing i set:

```
Dim ControlNumber As Range
Set ControlNumber = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)
Dim FilePath1 As String, FilePath2 As String, Filename As String
```

**EDIT**

```
On Error Resume Next
MkDir Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Main Folder"
MkDir Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Main Folder\Folder A\"
MkDir Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Main Folder\Folder B\"
On Error GoTo 0

FilePath1 = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Main Folder\Folder A\"
FilePath2 = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Main Folder\Folder B\"

Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
Filename = ControlNumber.Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FilePath1 & Filename & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

Sheets("Sheet2").Copy
Filename = ControlNumber.Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FilePath2 & Filename & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: Run-time error '1004':

Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Main Folder\Folder A\Filename1.xls.
There are several possible reasons:

The file name or path does not exist.
The file is being used by another program.
The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Comment: does the folder exist? is the file being used by another user/process?

Comment: Yes, all folders already exist and prepared... that'w why I'm getting confused with it that I still get the error message, but if I use Thisworkbook.path instead if Filepath1, I get Sheet1 saved... but error on sheet 2

Comment: i didnt got any errors... will run some tests again... just a sec

Comment: there may be the normal behavior of not working in certain path... pls try the code in the edit and then go to your profile "C:\Users\\[profilename]\Main Folder\ "

Answer (score 0):

You have included path seperator twice i.e in Filepath as well as while saving the file. remove "/" from Filename or while saving

```
FilePath1 = "C:\Main Folder\Folder A\"
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FilePath1 & "\" & Filename & ".xls"
```

Comment: oh uh... like my comment? :D

Comment: absolutely didn't saw your comment or else would have just liked it.

Comment: everything is fine ^^

Comment: Run-time error '1004':

Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Main Folder\Folder A\Filename1.xls.
There are several possible reasons:

The file name or path does not exist.
The file is being used by another program.
The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Comment: check whether the file with the same name already exist in the specified location.

Comment: Folder A and Folder B are both empty.

Comment: is there a file named Filename1 already opened. if yes then kindly close that excel file and rerun the macro